# Kotlin compiler shows compilation error and suggests to "change type from 'T' to 'T"' while there is only one T in the context

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, type-inference

I tried to implement some type classes from Haskell but confronted the issue that is probably a bug in the Kotlin compiler.

```kotlin
interface Semigroup<Instance> {
    infix fun Instance.assocOp(oother: Instance): Instance
}

inline fun <reified T: Semigroup<T>> Iterable<T>.concat() = this.reduce<T, T> { acc: T, t: T -> acc.assocOp(t) }
```

The error message is "Expected parameter of type T".

IDEA suggests to "Change type from 'T' to 'T'" (does nothing).

I expect `acc` to belong to the type `T` mentioned in generics. But because of some reason compiler tries to find some other type `T`. I tried to

- specify the type explicitly/implicitly
- build ignoring IDEA message
- change used version of Kotlin compiler (I have tried 1.4.20, 1.4.10, 1.3.72).

Nothing worked.

I suppose that writing the function without `reduce` (manually) may help to deal with it. Also, writing java code doing the same may help to mitigate the problem. But these solutions are only workarounds for the problem. Is the issue my fault or the compiler bug?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, it is not searchable. You should copy the code snippets and error messages into your question instead.

Comment: @Joffrey I thought it would be shown not via the link, but as is. But I was wrong. I'll follow your advice next time!

Comment: @zhelensky it is indeed a link, but it's still just as wrong as an inline screenshot. You're talking about code that we can't read in this post. The code is not searchable in this state. Please use a code block to paste your snippets of code, and copy-paste the error message as well, so that others can find your question and the answer more easily. You can still edit your question to fix this ;)

Comment: @Joffrey Sorry for the long delay, but I failed to find **edit** button after your previous message so I didn't edit it. However, I have found and edited it now after your hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error clearly is not helpful here. However, it is correct that the code should not compile IMO.

You're defining the method `assocOp` as a [member extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members). The extension applies to any type `T`, but it's a member of the interface `Semigroup<T>`.

To call that extension, you need both a receiver or type `T` *and* a receiver of type `Semigroup<T>` (acting as a context).

In your case, the type `T` both plays the role of the generic type parameter *and* of the `Semigroup<T>`, but you still need to have 2 "receivers" for your extension, even if both are the same instance.

Maybe try this:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Semigroup<T>> Iterable<T>.concat(): T =
    reduce<T, T> { t1: T, t2: T -> with(t1) { t1.assocOp(t2) } }
```

The `with(t1) { ... }` provides a context of type `Semigroup<T>`, while the `t1` used in `t1.assocOp(t2)` acts as the `T` receiver.

Comment: Thank you! (I accidentally forgot to thank)